# Can I safely replace a fiber SFP module with a copper one?

Tags: networking, sfp

I have an expensive piece of network equipment that has an SFP+ port on it. It came installed with a 10-gigabit fiber optic transceiver installed the port. According to the device's specifications, it supports both 1- and 10-gigabit rates via the SFP+ port. I don't currently have a 10-gigabit-capable device to plug into the other end, so I'd like to run it in its 1-gigabit mode.

Are SFP+ modules universal in the sense that I can just pop out the current fiber module and replace it with a 1-gigabit copper module that has an RJ45 in it? Or, would this be unsafe (or non-functional) in some way?

Answer (score 1):

You can probably use a copper 1GbE SFP adapter without issue. Hard to know without the specific details of your gear... But it's easy to test!

I've had to do the same with "[expensive pieces of networking equipment](http://www.celoxica.com/products/ultra-low-latency-market-data/)", where my interface and environmental needs dictated copper instead of fiber or DAC.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the info. Since I'm unfamiliar with the use of SFP modules in general, I just want to avoid any potential damage to the device in question. Sounds like it is worth a try.

Comment: What type of gear is it?

Comment: It's just a one-off device from a custom hardware vendor. I don't have great documentation for it, hence my quick sanity check.